# How to add custom library to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, survey

I want to import SurveyJS from https://surveyjs.io/Overview/Library/ but is not listed on nuget package on visual studio 2017. How can I custom import it?

Comment: Just copy the script files into your project. If you're running builder scripts you can have it move the files into a "build" folder with the rest of your packages.

Comment: The documentation answers this:  https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library?id=Add-Survey-into-your-Web-Page

Answer (score 0):

Javascript libraries are usually added to NPM not Nuget.

You can install surveyjs through npm, check the docs https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs

```
npm install survey-angular
npm install survey-jquery
npm install survey-knockout
npm install survey-react
npm install survey-vue
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of MVC you are using you might download the npm package, use a Bower package, or Computers the scripts manually into your applications static files directory.  Then to have it available in a view you will need to reference it in your HTML using the script tag, with the source set to the location of the actual JavaScript file.

You could also add it to a bundle that your loading.

Typically you're matter layout will have an optional section for scripts, so that you can reference it on the specific view you need it for.

I believe the razor helper is used like this on your view...

`@section scripts{
   <script src="path to js file"></script>
}`

On your layout, near the bottom of the body you should have a corresponding section that looks like this...

`@RenderSection("scripts",false)`

The false makes it optional.